# Read nested json display each key value [From mySQL]

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to read a nested JSON data where the key values are sub nested key and values but it does not seem to work. 
first json data from database table [column: Roles]

```
$json = array();
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM u_info WHERE bid=".$branch);
while ($rs = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {    
    $rs['img'] = getImg($rs['img']);
    $query = $db->query('SELECT roles FROM wp_roles WHERE userid='.$rs['id'])->fetch_assoc();
    $rs['role'] = json_decode($query['roles']); // already a json format
    $json[] = $rs; 
}
exit(json_encode($json));// convert to json AJAX response works
```

Then json result as follows

```
{ 
    "academics":{ 
        "class":"true",
        "employee":"false",
        "students":"true",
        "subject":"false",
        "all":"true"
    },
    "exam":{ 
        "exams":"false",
        "schedule":"false",
        "result":"false",
        "marksheet":"false",
        "all":"false"
    },
    "timetable":{ 
        "class":"false",
        "teacher":"false",
        "all":"false"
    },
    "attendance":{ 
        "students":"true",
        "teacher":"true",
        "all":"true"
    }
}
```

undefined json length [JAVASCRIPT]

```
// parse nested json 
var json = JSON.parse(data)

console.log(json.role) // works and print above json
console.log(json.role.length) // undefined

// for loop not works
for(i = 0; i < json.role.length; i++){

   for(y = 0; y < json.role[i].length; y++){
      // json.role.academics.class === true [if condition]
       if(json.role[i][y] === true){
         //......
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above JSON is an object which is why its length is coming undefined.

The way you are trying to read the data - the JSON response should have an array of objects referenced via "roles" property - in below format should work. Please check the response.

```
{
    "roles": [{
            "academics": {
                "class": "true",
                "employee": "false",
                "students": "true",
                "subject": "false",
                "all": "true"
            }
        },
        {
            "exam": {
                "exams": "false",
                "schedule": "false",
                "result": "false",
                "marksheet": "false",
                "all": "false"
            }
        },
        {
            "timetable": {
                "class": "false",
                "teacher": "false",
                "all": "false"
            }
        },
        {
            "attendance": {
                "students": "true",
                "teacher": "true",
                "all": "true"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```